# SF2 - Sonata: How to get parameter from parameter.yml in entity

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I used the sonata admin bundle.
HOW can I make entity to engage parameters.yml to?
Either directly or via service ....

I have to do some tidying work in Postremove, I need here disclosures paths, access data and more.
This I will not write to the hard Entitiy, but parameters.yml pick from.

Timo

Answer (score 1):

`Entity` class is not a place for putting business logic. As far as I know you can't define `entity` as a service.

What you want to do should be solved by creating [Event listener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html) which you can define as a service and pass value from `parameters.yml`. This listener should listen on your `postRemove` event.

Your `services.yml`:

```
services:
    service_name:
        class: Acme\Your\ListenerClass
        arguments: [%your_parameter_from_yml%]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postRemove }
```

Your ListenerClass:

```
class ListenerClass
{

public function __construct($your_param_from_parameters)
{
    $this->param = $your_param_from_parameters
}

/**
 * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
 */
public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof YourEntity) {
        //DO THE MAGIC!!
    }
}
}
```